# check checkbox in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to automatically uncheck or check children's checkboxes:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>1 <input type='checkbox' /></li>
    <ul>
        <li>1.1 <input type='checkbox'' /></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>1.1.1 <input type='checkbox' /></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$('li input').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $(this).parent().next().children("li").children("input").attr("checked", true);
        console.log("checked")
    }else{
        $(this).parent().next().children("li").children("input").attr("checked", false);
        console.log("not checked")
    }
})
```

But it only works for the first occurence. I don't understand why because the 1.1 change and the event change is not triggered

http://jsfiddle.net/D8ZdU/

Thanks

Comment: It's obvious. At first your HTML is not valid! Inside `<ul>` tag can be only li elements, but you put there also `<ul>` tags. Move nested `<ul>`-s into `<li>`-s. Then you need to rewrite your js code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you correct your HTML, to the following:

```
<ul>
    <li>1 <input type="checkbox" />
        <ul>
            <li>1.1 <input type="checkbox" />
                <ul>
                    <li>1.1.1 <input type="checkbox" /></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then the following jQuery works:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(
    function(){
        var state = this.checked ? true : false;
        $(this).next('ul').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', state);
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/D8ZdU/1/).

The problems with your HTML are that a `ul` element is not a valid child of another `ul`, or `ol`, element. The only valid children of `ul` (and `ol`) is the `li` element, *everything* else is invalid, unless it's contained within an `li`.

References:

- [`:checkbox` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use closest method:

```
$('ul input').change(function(){
   var $this = $(this).closest('ul');
   $this.add($this.nextAll()).find("input").prop("checked", this.checked);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LpGsS/

Note that your markup need modofication why not using `li` elements?

```
<ul>
    <li>1 <input type='checkbox' /></li>
    <li>1.1<input type='checkbox' /></li>
    <li>1.1.1 <input type='checkbox' /></li>
</ul>
```

```
$('ul input').change(function(){
    $(this).parent().nextAll().find("input").prop("checked", this.checked);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JjvKH/

Answer (score 0):

For the first checkbox, "parent" is the `<li>` that's in the outer `<ul>`. For the others, their "parent" is the `<li>` that's isolated in another `<ul>` and has no "next".